If $0<\alpha<30^{0}$, then find value of $\log_{2}\left(\dfrac{8\cos(30^{0}-2\alpha)-\dfrac{8}{\cot(\alpha)+\cot(30^{0}-\alpha)}}{\sqrt3}\right)$
The question is

If $0<\alpha<30^{\circ}$, then find value of $\log_{2}\left(\dfrac{8\cos(30^{\circ}-2\alpha)-\dfrac{8}{\cot(\alpha)+\cot(30^{\circ}-\alpha)}}{\sqrt3}\right)$ is

(a) $0$
(b) $2$
(c) $4$
(d) $8$


My Approach: Since given expression has constant value so it must be true for any $\alpha$ so I replaced $\alpha$ with $15^{\circ}$
So expression inside logarithm function turn out to be $\dfrac{8-\dfrac{8}{2\cot(15^{\circ})}}{\sqrt3}=1\cdot 022$ and becuase of given answer is $2$ so it must be $4$ but value of this expression is somewhat $1\cdot 022$
Thanks to all. I got answer as $4$ Using $\alpha =15^{\circ}$
Also I would Like to get proper and shorter method if any?

The given expression doesn't seem to have a constant value.

@MartinR $\cot(30^\circ-\alpha)=\cot15^\circ$ then

@M.Riyan I've solved using other method and I got constant value. I'll put that too in solution

@M.Riyan it indeed does have a constant value, just checked on desmos.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ekwmwhamyx

@EdmaandVladPhiyik o thanks, I now noticed it.

Why I am getting downvote on this post ??

I would like to know, how you deduced the given expression into that last form. The answer lies there, I guess.

If you already know that the expression is constant then the simplest way may be to consider the limit for $\alpha \to 0$. Then $\cot \alpha \to \infty$ and the fraction approaches $8 \cos(30^0)/\sqrt 3$.

I believe the following method is quite short
\begin{align*}
\cot(\alpha) + \cot(30^{\circ} - \alpha) & = \frac{\cos(\alpha)\sin(30^{\circ} - \alpha) + \cos(30^{\circ}-\alpha)\sin(\alpha)}{\sin(\alpha)\sin(30^{\circ}-\alpha)} \\
& = \frac{\sin(30^{\circ})}{\sin(\alpha)\sin(30^{\circ}-\alpha)} \\
& = \frac{1}{2\sin(\alpha)\sin(30^{\circ}-\alpha)} \\
& = \frac{1}{\cos(30^{\circ} - 2\alpha) - \cos(30^{\circ})}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
  \log_{2}\left( \frac{8\cos(30^{\circ} - 2\alpha) - 8(\cos(30^{\circ} - 2\alpha) - \cos(30^{\circ}))}{\sqrt{3}} \right) = \log_{2}\frac{8\cos(30^{\circ})}{\sqrt{3}} = \log_{2}4 = 2.
\end{align*}
Hence the value is 2.

I calculated and got the value as 2.
Please recheck your answer.
Thank you.


Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
